# Deleting a key-value pair from hash (RUBY)

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

```
movies = {
  StarWars: 4.8, 
  Divergent: 4.7
  }

print movies
```

This code returns a hash:

```
{:StarWars=>4.8, :Divergent=>4.7}
```

When I try to delete a key-value pair and print movies again:

```
movies = {
  StarWars: 4.8, 
  Divergent: 4.7
  }


movies = movies.delete("Divergent".to_sym)
print movies
```

I get :

```
4.7
```

How do I delete a key-value pair, so that after I ask to print the contents of movies hash I get :

```
{:StarWars=>4.8}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Hash#delete](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete) returns the value of provided key, `movies.delete("Divergent".to_sym)` returns `4.7`, and you reassign it to `movies`, now `movies` is `4.7`.

So you could just `delete` and don't reassign:

```rb
movies.delete("Divergent".to_sym)
print movies # => {:StarWars=>4.8}
```